# Writing to Dynamo table works fine, but reading throws DynamoDBMappingException

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb

Executing `orderRequestDao.save(new OrderRequest("5000", "body"));` successfully places a record in Dynamo.  Any attempts to read returns:

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
could not invoke null on class 
com.cfa.fulfillmentApi.model.OrderRequest 
with value 100 of type class java.lang.String] with root cause
```

(Record with id: 100 exists)

I'm using the following jars (aws.sdk.version: 1.11.86):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

DyamoDb config:

Primary partition key: `id (String)`

Dao:

```
@EnableScan
public interface OrderRequestDao extends CrudRepository<OrderRequest, String> {
    OrderRequest findOne(String s);
    OrderRequest save(OrderRequest or);
}
```

Domain object:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "dev_transx")
public class OrderRequest {

    private String id;
    private String body;

    public OrderRequest(String id, String body) {
        this.id = id;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public OrderRequest() {}

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, body='%s']",
                id, body);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

}
```

I've tried just about every data type for id in the domain class, but no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I removed `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` since it was already in `spring-data-dynamodb`

Most importantly I added a setter for ID in the domain class.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a setter method for the field works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For those who like me found this question through the error message but are not happy with all proposed solutions:

Annotate the getter method which cause the problem with `@DynamoDBIgnore`

Excerpt from AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBIgnore.html):

> Annotation for marking a class property as non-modeled. Applied to the getter method or the class field for a non-modeled property. If the annotation is applied directly to the class field, the corresponding getter and setter must be declared in the same class.

> All getter methods not marked with this annotation are assumed to be modeled properties and included in any save() requests.